# kivy.lang Builder doesn't evaluate simple expressions

Tags: kivy

While working with kivy.lang Builder I performed some simple arithmetic and it's not working, no error message even.

```
Builder.load_string ('''
<RootWidget>:
    text: 'beautiful Flower Pics '
    font_size: 50
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.width * 0.5, root.height
        source: 'newflower.png'
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ration: False
```

here at `root.widht * 0.5` multiplication is not being done. suggestion, hint, advice?

Comment: What does RootWidget subclass? Is it a layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `RootWidget` is a `Layout` of some sort, you need to set your [`size_hint`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#understanding-the-size-hint-property-in-widget). `size_hint` defaults to `1, 1`, and will override your specified sizes. If you set `size_hint: None, None` then this should size as expected - and depending on the specific type of `Layout`, you may be able to skip setting `size` altogether and just use `size_hint: 0.5, 1` to get the same effect.